# Using feature state for icon image, but expression parser is complaining

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use a feature state in a case statement for an icon-image with a zoom step, but the parser is refusing to take it, even though there should only be one at a time, am I missing something here?

```
        layout: {
          'icon-image': ["case",
            ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
            ['step', ['zoom'], 'marker-13', 7, 'marker-17'],
            ['step', ['zoom'], 'active-marker-13', 7, 'active-marker-17']
          ],
          'icon-size': 1
        },
```

Error received:

> Only one zoom-based "step" or "interpolate" subexpression may be used in an expression.

Using 1.6.0.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

As the message is indicating, you can't have two separate `['zoom']` expressions.

You can solve this by flipping your expression inside out so the `zoom` is on the outside.

```js
{
    layout: {
        'icon-image': ['step', ['zoom'],
            ['case',
                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                'marker-13',
                'active-marker-13'
            ],
            7,
            ['case',
                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                'marker-17',
                'active-marker-17'
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, this yields: "feature-state" data expressions are not supported with layout properties so I guess what I am trying to achieve is currently not possible sadly

Comment: Oh, I always forget that. :/ You can probably find another way to achieve this effect by creating a layer which contains just one feature, the hovered-over one, and updating that as the mouse moves around. Or possibly using a Marker instead of a layer.

Comment: yeah that is actually what I have right now (separate layer with a filter), but wanted to use feature state everywhere in the app, but given the limitations I need to mix both approaches for now